# How to give ADO.NET Parameters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I want to create a SQL command that adds record to DB. I tried the following code but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Product_table Values(@Product_Name,@Product_Price,@Product_Profit,@p)", connect);
SqlParameter ppar = new SqlParameter();
ppar.ParameterName = "@Product_Name";
ppar.Value = textBox1.Text;
MessageBox.Show("Done");
comaand.Parameters.Add(ppar);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, it looks like you're using .NET. Using parameters is as easy as:

C#

```
 string sql = "SELECT empSalary from employee where salary = @salary";
 SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(/* connection info */);
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("salary", txtSalary.Text);
```

Comment: [Can we stop using `AddWithValue` already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: I think so. You should try first and then let me know any problem about it.

Comment: btw, "salary" is mentioned without @ at AddWithValue in the code above. Is @ optional or required?

Comment: @FelixPamittan A down-side of moving away from `AddWithValue` is that `command.Parameters.Add("salary", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtSalary.Text;`  falls over dead if the string is empty. And if you want to avoid it, you are forced to specify a `Size` for all types; which becomes extraordinarliy tedious, and even more extraordinarily error-prone. For example: *What is the size of an empty string?* *What is the size of an `int`?* *What is the size of a `uniqueidentifier`?* *What is the size of an `nvarchar(max)`? These are all things that have answers; but (very) non-obvious.

Comment: @ character is not needed for the parameter name, and fails for some database vendors as they have different symbols.

Answer (score 9):

Should use something like the following:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Product_table Values(@Product_Name, @Product_Price, @Product_Profit, @p)", connect);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Product_Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, ProductNameSizeHere).Value = txtProductName.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Product_Price", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtProductPrice.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Product_Profit", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtProductProfit.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p", SqlDbType.NVarChar, PSizeHere).Value = txtP.Text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Assuming @p parameter is some NVarChar.

Better avoid using AddWithValue, see why here:
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Also at INSERT SQL statement better provide names of the values (as defined in the database) before the values themselves, as shown at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Answer (score 1):

I think this is useful for u

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("inserting", con);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.Add("@Firstname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Lastname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: don't think the question was about how to use with a stored procedure, they were trying a simple INSERT

Comment: however the command.Parameters.Add("@ParamName", SqlDbType.xx).Value = someValue is the best syntax indeed (as explained at https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ )

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter",yourValue);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I mean you forgot to use command.executeNonQuery();

Comment: [Can we stop using `AddWithValue` already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)