# Incorrect syntax near keyword ' .Unclosed quotation mark in stored procedure

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am getting an error(Incorrect syntax near keyword ' .Unclosed quotation mark) while inserting record but data get inserted into table properly.How to handle that.If error occure,it gives no of affected row as zero,so my logic fails.

Message : Testing is going on. Let's find out it.

Here is my sp:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcInsertRecord
    @Name VARCHAR(30),
    @mobile_no VARCHAR(30),
    @message VARCHAR(30),
    @Address VARCHAR(30),
    @Designation VARCHAR(30)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table1 (Name, Mobile, Message, Address, Designation) 
    VALUES (@Name, @mobile_no, @message, @Address, @Designation)
END
```

Comment: can you give us the script you are using to run the stored procedure?

Comment: Sound you should use SQL parameters. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420045/how-to-give-ado-net-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code and table columns allow nulls????

```
Alter PROCEDURE ProcInsertRecord

    @Name VARCHAR(30),
    @mobile_no VARCHAR(30),
    @message VARCHAR(30),
    @Address VARCHAR(30),
    @Designation VARCHAR(30),
    @Flag VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN

    if(@Flag = 'I')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Table1 (Name, Mobile, Message, Address, Designation) 
        VALUES ('Abcd', '1234567890', 'Hii', 'Ahmedabad', 'developer')
    END
END
```