# How can i edit Login Form in C# using SQL parameters?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

So i have Login Form where i need to insert Name and Password from sql database, but it gets an error because my fields are nvarchar, so i'd like to edit it using sql parameters.

Code of "Enter" button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (DocName.Text == "" || PassTb.Text == "")
                MessageBox.Show("Enter login and password");
            else
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select Count(*) from Doctor where DocName='"+DocName.Text+"' and DocPass='"+PassTb.Text+"'", conn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1"){
                    Home H = new Home();
                    H.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid login or password");
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

I think if i use cmd.parameters.AddWithValue it will solve my problems, but i can't figure out how to do it, so i'll be glad for any help

Edit: okay, so i actually edited the code and added parameters, but i still can't figure out how to proceed with DataAdapter..so it gives an error that "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Must declare the scalar variable "@DocName"."

Edited code for the button:

```
public static SqlDataAdapter CreateCustomerAdapter(SqlConnection conn)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

        // Create the SelectCommand.
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Doctor " +
            "WHERE DocName = @DocName AND DocPass = @DocPass", conn);

        // Add the parameters for the SelectCommand.
        command.Parameters.Add("@DocName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        command.Parameters.Add("@DocName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);

        adapter.SelectCommand = command;

        return adapter;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = CreateCustomerAdapter(conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {
            Home H = new Home();
            H.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid login or password");
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: [Don't use `AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), [it's evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: Not quite as evil as SQL injection, though. Or passwords stored in plaintext.

Comment: As for what you *do* have, it is wide open to injection; someone could easily log in by passing the "DocName" as `' OR 1 = 1; --` and inputting literally *anything* for their password. `Parameters.Add` is what you want, per the linked 2 articles in my last comment. Plus, as @JeroenMostert has hinted, it appears your passwords are plain text, which is a huge problem too;  **always** stored passwords as a salt and hash combination.

Comment: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to give ADO.NET Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420045/how-to-give-ado-net-parameters)

Comment: There are literally thousands of articles on the internet on how to do this. This question has been asked since .Net 1.1 in 2005

Comment: I'd also suggest you read up on [security best practice](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/) there is SOOO much wrong with this

Comment: If, having studied all the examples etc, you're still stuck, then please update the question with your attempt to use the parameters and explain what went wrong when you tried to compile / run it. Then we can help you, because you'll have an actual problem rather than what looks like a "I haven't studied / tried anything much yet" issue.

Comment: @ADyson ok, i edited the original post

Comment: Thanks. Your parameters and command are completely unconnected to your data adapter. If you notice, the adapter only references the query and the connection. The error is telling you that you've set a parameter placeholder in the query but haven't actually added a parameter for it into the adapter. If you want to use a SqlDataAdapter, then you need to attach the SqlCommand to the adapter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: i'm sorry, @ADyson, i used SqlDataAdapter method and edited the code in question, but i still have the next error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "The variable name '@DocName' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
Must declare the scalar variable "@DocPass"."

Comment: You add the same parameter two times. `command.Parameters.Add("@DocName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);command.Parameters.Add("@DocName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);` The error message will tell you that. Look at the query and look at that code and with the error message I think it should now be obvious where you went wrong.

Comment: thank you! i don't know how i didn't notice that
but i still have the error such as ""The parameterized query '(@DocName nvarchar(50),@DocPass nvarchar(50))SELECT * FROM Docto' expects the parameter '@DocName', which was not supplied."

i think maybe it's because i don't insert login and password through textbox in command.Parameters.Add("@DocName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
command.Parameters.Add("@DocName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);

i try to replace SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50 with DocName.Text but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I am not sure if you phrased your question properly but I understood you want to query the database based on the username and password provided on the login form ?

if(exists)
{ Login?}

Comment: @KeronTzul, exactly! it just needs to log in if there's such fields in the database, but i don't know how to replace SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50 with TextBoxes where i insert Login and Password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following code to check if your username or password is correct.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connstr = @"connstr";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connstr);
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "select * from Doctor WHERE DocName = @DocName AND DocPass = @DocPass";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql,connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocName",txtName.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocPass", txtPwd.Text);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if(reader.HasRows)
            {
                Form2 form2 = new Form2();
                form2.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtPwd.PasswordChar = '*';
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very Old Snippit of code i had for a small project but

The way it works is a Class exists to hash the password (encrypting it and Decrypting it) when a user add his/her password the application encrypts whatever is on the password field and matches it with what is on the database IF the username and password match a record ont he user table it will proceed to login in.

```
try
                {
                    string LoginCommand = "select * from user_login where UserName ='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
                    using (SqlConnection LoginCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConfigString"].ToString()))
                    using (SqlCommand LoginCom = LoginCon.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        label8.Text = "Finding User in system..";
                        LoginCom.CommandText = LoginCommand;

                        LoginCon.Open();

                        using (SqlDataReader Reader = LoginCom.ExecuteReader())
                        {


                            if (Reader.Read())
                            {
                                //label8.Text = priv;
                                label8.Text = "User Found!";
                                Password = Reader["EncrPassword"].ToString();
                                priv = Reader["Privillages"].ToString();
                                IsExist = true;
                            }



                        }

                        LoginCon.Close();

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }

                if (IsExist)  //if record exis in db , it will return true, otherwise it will return false
                {
                    if (Cryptography.Decrypt(Password).Equals(textBox2.Text))
                    {


                        label8.Text = "Making sure Everything is Ready!";

                        User = textBox1.Text;
                        //    MessageBox.Show("Login Success", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        GetAcces();
                        this.Hide();
                        MainWindow frm1 = new MainWindow();
                        frm1.ShowDialog();

                        //We Show pop up here.


                        try
                        {
                            // show
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {

                            throw;
                        }




                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Password is wrong!...", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        label8.Text = "Your Password or UserName is incorrect - Please Try again!";
                    }

                }
                else  //showing the error message if user credential is wrong
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter the valid credentials", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);


                }



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Cannot Locate Server");
            }
```

Comment: it's very useful, but i just need some simple solution to end the project, so i want to figure out how to insert Login And Password through TextBox instead of command.Parameters.Add("@DocName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50); 
i need to replace SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50 with DocName.Text which is textbox, but it doesn't work properly

Comment: command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = customerID;

Answer (score 0):

I Think this is what you are looking for

command.Parameters.Add("@DocName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);

you must add

command.Parameters["@DocName"].Value = DocName.text;

That way you are passing the value of docname.text to the parameters while still making sure it is accepting the correct datatype before it.