# When I try to send data from one table to another, I get an error

Tags: c#, database

I'm trying to insert a data into a table that comes from another table - something like this:

```
decimal saldo = getDbSaldo($@"SELECT Balance FROM clients WHERE Pin='{pin}' AND CardNumber = '{numeroCartao}'");
insertExtrato($@"insert into  MoveInfo (CardNumber, Deposit, Saldo, Withdraw, DataHora) Values({numeroCartao}, {deposit}, {saldo}, {withdraw}, getDate())");
```

The data is getting there:

[image]

But when I get it working, I always get this error:

[image]

I've been stuck on this for two days.

Comment: What is the actual runtime value of the SQL command you're executing?  Note that munging strings together to build SQL commands in this way is a SQL injection vulnerability.  You should be using query parameters instead.

Comment: Probably if you use parameters instead of concatenating strings you will never experience this error. Now please tell us what values are present in the variables used for the INSERT INTO statement

Comment: but the problem can be SQL injection ? @David

Comment: @EmanuelSantos: It certainly can, yes.  If you *don't control* the syntax of your SQL code and just allow it to be built from anything then that SQL code could be valid, could be invalid, could be malicious, could be anything.

Comment: Suppose that _saldo_ is **10.42**. What do you think will happen if the conversion of the decimal value to a string gives back a comma instead of a point?

Comment: IDK how to do it but I will search

Comment: Consider what the SQL being executed would look like of any of your *concatenated* values contains a comma or delimiters. *ALWAYS* use a parameterised query.

Comment: By the way. It seems that you are executing an INSERT INTO with an ExecuteReader. This, while still working, is not the correct way. You should use ExecuteNonQuery for that query

Comment: @Stu think that's it, how do I replace the "," by "." ?

Comment: @Steve I think is that I need a think to change the format I already saw that I dont know where I'm gonna search

Comment: @EmanuelSantos: Use parameterized queries and you won't have to.  The problem you're experiencing now isn't something you need to (or should) solve, it's something that shouldn't be a problem in the first place if you use proper database access.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31420045/328193) is the first SO question I found on the subject, though there are likely many more.  Your favorite search engine can help you find "ado.net parameterized queries".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now is the time to replace your SQL-injectable code with parameterized queries.

What's happening is that you're not controlling your SQL code.  You're munging strings together and executing them as code.  The result could be valid SQL code, could be invalid SQL code, could be malicious, could be anything.  You're not in control of it so you don't know.

Always add values as parameters.  An example would be:

```
var query = "insert into MoveInfo (CardNumber, Deposit, Saldo, Withdraw, DataHora) Values(@numeroCartao, @deposit, @saldo, @withdraw, getDate())";
var cmd = new SqlCommand() { Connection = cn, CommandText = query };
cmd.Parameters.Add("@numeroCartao", SqlDbType.Int).Value = numeroCartao;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@deposit", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = deposit;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@saldo", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = saldo;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@withdraw", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = withdraw;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Note that I *completely guessed* on the `SqlDbType` values to use here.  You'll of course want to use whatever matches your database schema.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm going to try to use this

Comment: worked thanks i'll start changing the rest of the code to stay like that too :)