# Subtract the quantity sales in a datagrid

Tags: c#

I want to update the quantity in the table after button clicked

```
cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbProduct ", con);
long var_stock = 0;
long var_sell = 0;
long result = 0;
var_stock = Convert.ToInt64(numericUpDown1.Value);
var_sell = qty;
result = var_stock - var_sell;
cm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tbProduct SET pqty = @pqty '" + result+ "' WHERE pid LIKE '" + txtPid + "' ", con);
   
con.Open();
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
   
this.Dispose();
```

I'm getting this error

> must declare the scalar variable @ptqy+

formproduct with datagrid
formorder with datagrid

Is there any solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to give ADO.NET Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420045/how-to-give-ado-net-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed parameters with a dynamically created statement, and in the statement you defined a parameter `@pqty` that you don't set.

Anyway, it's a good practice to avoid the dynamic creation of sql statement.

Try

```
cm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tbProduct SET pqty = @pqty WHERE pid LIKE @txtPid", con);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pqty", result);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtPid", txtPid);
```

See [SqlCommand.Parameters Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) for more info.

Comment: that shows an error https://ibb.co/rpSHr1K

Comment: If txtPid is a control then you must use the property that returns the text written inside it. I can imagine `txtPid.Text`? You doesn't specify the type of application that you're developing, so I don't know wich types of controls you're using.